# SVN - folder checkout and merges

Tags: svn, release

I have the following scenario with code organized as:

```
Product
->Core
->Module1
->Module2
->Module3
->...
->ModuleN
```

All of the code is managed by SVN. From time to time we'd like to be able to select module(s) from the tree in order create a specific set of sourcecode to check out - iow we're looking at using SVN as a "release packaging tool". Most of the time we want to accomplish this from the "trunk" but sometimes it might be desireable to do it from a "branch". One more important note to mention is that every module folder contains config- and documentation fragments which we would like to be able to "merge" depending on the selected modules for a given release package.

Is this possible to accomplish using SVN alone or do we need another tool which might hook into SVN. Any other tool which might be a complement?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in several ways. One way is to create a working copy of so-called [mixed revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs).

Another way is to use [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html). This is a very flexible way of plugging several parts of your repository together. It also allows you to pin certain parts to a specific revision.

Comment: Hi Atafar! Thanks for your suggestion. Would these approaches also support the automatic merging of the config and documentation files I mentioned. As I mentioned in my initial question I want the process to also be able to merge the config- and documentation-fragments that are part of the selected folder checkouts...

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want to merge automatically. You can merge if you explicitly specify a target. Also, check-out the `--accept` option of `merge` for automatic conflict resolution. With older svn clients you cannot merge externals transparently. For svn clients <= 1.6, only `status` and `update` work transparently. I must admit I have not attempted merges across externals with svn client >= 1.7 yet.